# How to access Firefox cache from webdriver?

Tags: python, firefox, caching, webdriver

I'm able to access pages like `about:cache-entry?client=HTTP&sb=1&key=(some URL)` directly in Firefox, but when it renders the page, it certainly gets the data from some storage. How can I access the latter from Python Firefox Webdriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page returned by such an `about:cache-entry?...` URL contains a line like this one:

```
file on disk: /home/fviktor/.mozilla/firefox/7jx6k3hx.default/Cache/CF7379D8d01
```

It is the full pathname of the cache file if any. I think you'll be able to read that file from Python as usual, but I haven't tested it yet. The pathname can also be `none` in the case of small files cached only in memory. You can get the file contents by parsing the hex dump on the returned page in this case.

Comment: If you look in your `about:cache` you'll see that some cache items are on disk (*Disk cache device*) and some are in memory (*Memory cache device*) those in memory don't have a path associated with them and the OP wants to know how he can access them.

Comment: Those `about:cache-entry?...` pages contain the full hex dump of the cached files, even if they are from the memory cache. A slow solution would be to parse that hex dump. For example it should work for you in Firefox: `about:cache-entry?client=HTTP&sb=1&key=http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png`